# Rudin exercise 3.3

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Several of the proposed solutions I have seen for this theorem seem to have typos, so I was hoping someone could look over this attempt. The problem is:

> If $s_1 = \sqrt{2}$, and
> $$s_{n+1} = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_n}}$$
> for $n = 1,2,3, \ldots$, prove that $\{s_n\}$ converges, and that $s_n < 2$ for $n = 1,2,3, \ldots$.

My attempt is below.

> By Theorem 3.14, it suffices for convergence to prove that $\{s_n\}$ is monotonic and bounded. Of course, we have $s_n \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by construction, so $\{s_n\}$ is bounded below by $0$. We next prove that $s_n < 2$ for all $n$ by induction. We of course have $s_1 = \sqrt{2} < 2$. Suppose inductively that for some $k \geq 1$, we have $s_k < 2$. As the square root function is strictly monotonically increasing, this implies that $\sqrt{s_k} < 2$. It then follows that
> \begin{align*} 
> s_{k+1} = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_k}} < \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_k}} < \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}} < \sqrt{2 + 2} = \sqrt{4} = 2,
> \end{align*}
> closing the induction. Therefore, $\{s_n\}$ is bounded above by $2$. Furthermore, I claim that $\{s_n\}$ is monotonically increasing. We will show by induction on $n$ that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $s_n \leq s_{n+1}$. When $n = 1$, we have
> \begin{align*}
> s_1 = \sqrt{2} < \sqrt{2 + 0} < \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}} = s_2
> \end{align*}
> since the square function is monotonically increasing and $0 < \sqrt{2}$. Now, suppose inductively that for some $n \geq 2$, we have $s_{n-1} \leq s_{n}$, so $\sqrt{s_{n-1}} \leq \sqrt{s_n}$. Therefore, $\sqrt{s_{n-1}} - \sqrt{s_n} \leq 0$, so $2 + \sqrt{s_{n-1}} - \sqrt{s_n} \leq 2$. By definition,
> $2 + \sqrt{s_{n-1}} = s_n^2$, so we have $s_n - \sqrt{s_n} - 2 \leq 0$. Therefore, $s_n \leq 2 + \sqrt{s_n}$. Taking square roots, we find $\sqrt{s_n} \leq \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{s_n}} = s_{n+1}$, closing the induction. Therefore, $\{s_n\}$ is increasing and bounded, and thus convergent.

How does this look? Is there a way to make the argument more rigorous?

Comment: as I see it it is fine